# How can I delete something from my Flash template?

Tags: flash

I want to edit some templates but the problem is when I am trying to delete the blue bar the result is the text will not be shown. Here is a picture of what I have:

[image: picture]

I don't know where to delete the blue bar (Graphics, sprite, or image?) I want to remove that bar and the text is the only one to be shown and of course I can edit the text for my project.  Thanks!

I have also [asked this at Farsa.gr](http://farsa.gr/forum/showthread.php?t=34879).

Comment: Make in the title clear what you want. This title only fits if your goal is to hire Flash experts. Also, watch typos, the more properly your question is written, the more chance you will get an answer.

Comment: @Dykam, you have sufficient reputation that can fix some of those problems yourself.

Comment: I don't feel like editing others messages, but okay, I'll do next  time.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to edit MovieClip. But I may be wrong. Try double-clicking it on the Stage and you should enter Edit Mode where you can select just the box and delete it. Depending on how complex the MovieClip is, you may need to keep double-clicking the blue bar until you've reached a level where you can delete only the blue-bar graphics..

If this doesn't work, perhaps you are dealing with a compiled SWF or a Component instance. These cannot be edited so easily. Templates are often designed so that you can't "steal" their code. Sometimes the developer of the template would be happy to edit these things for you if you have the $$$. In this case, you could try drawing a black box over top of it to hide it.